# Adding ON DUPLICATE to looping INSERT INTO mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
while($table = mysql_fetch_array($res_from)) { 
// echo($table[0] . "<br />"); // optional, only for show the name tables

$table=$table[0];

$tableinfo  = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SHOW CREATE TABLE $table  ",$dblink1)); // retrieve table structure from mysite1.com 

mysql_query(" $tableinfo[1] ",$dblink2); // use found structure to make table on mysite2.com

$res_to = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table  ",$dblink1); // select all content from table mysite1.com  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res_to, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
    $sql_error = "";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (".implode(", ",array_keys($row)).") VALUES ('".implode("', '",array_values($row))."')  ",$dblink2); // insert one row into new table on mysite2.com`enter code here`

    $sql_error = mysql_error($dblink2);
}
if (@$sql_error) {
    echo $sql_error."<br />";
}else {
    echo "copy table ".$table." done.<br />";
}
    flush();
}
```

**How do i add ON DUPLICATE to**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (".implode(", ",array_keys($row)).") VALUES ('".implode("', '",array_values($row))."')  ",$dblink2);
```

`(".implode(", ",array_keys($row)).")` is array of column name.

`('".implode("', '",array_values($row))."')` is array of column value.

Comment: pls don't use `mysql_`. it is deprecated now use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead

Comment: what if handling it with `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATES`

Comment: @4givN INSERT IGNORE will only skip a duplicate instead of changing the value. and i don't know how to handle ON DUPLICATE on array column name & value , thats why i post this question